# Finding multiple duplicate letters in components within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, console.log

```
let ItCompanies=["Facebook", "Google", "Microsoft", "Apple", "IBM", "Oracle" , "Amazon"]

let arr=[]
for(i=0;i<ItCompanies.length;i++){
    if(ItCompanies[i].includes("o")){
        arr.push(ItCompanies[i])
       
    }
    
}

for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    let split=arr[i]
    for(i=0;i<split.length;i++){
        let split=arr[i].split("")
        if(split.indexOf("o")!= split.lastIndexOf("o")){
            console.log(arr[i])
        }
    }
    
}
```

Finding multiple duplicate letters in components within an array
Can you share with me a shorter way of doing this?

Comment: couldn't this `split.indexOf("o")!= split.lastIndexOf("o")` go in the first loop (or something similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to use arr on your code. Here is my solution:

```
let ItCompanies=["Facebook", "Google", "Microsoft", "Apple", "IBM", "Oracle" , "Amazon"]

for (let i = 0; i < ItCompanies.length; i++){
    if (ItCompanies[i].indexOf("o") != ItCompanies[i].lastIndexOf("o")){
        console.log(ItCompanies[i])
    }
}
```

Or you can use forEach method of javascript array like this:

```
let ItCompanies=["Facebook", "Google", "Microsoft", "Apple", "IBM", "Oracle" , "Amazon"]

ItCompanies.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.indexOf("o") != item.lastIndexOf("o")){
        console.log(item)
    }  
})
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, can you give me a green check mark to my answer? ;)